# wxPython, nested panels and accelerators

Tags: wxpython

Accelerators on wxPython do not seem to work with nested panels. In other words:

```
    -----------------------------------------------
    | Main panel                                  |
    | -----------------    -----------------      |
    | | Subpanel 1    |    | Subpanel 2    |      |
    | | accelerator   |    | accelerator   |      |
    | | key for 'a'   |    | key for 'b'   |      |
    | -----------------    -----------------      |
    -----------------------------------------------
```

When a control in subpanel 1 has focus, I want Alt+b to still trigger the control in subpanel 2 that uses b as its accelerator key. How do I do this?

If it matters, I'm loading the panel with xrc into a plain old wx.Frame.

Answer (score 0):

If the main panel has the accelerator table with Alt+b, this should work.  Maybe the sub-panels have their own accelerator tables that are conflicting?  You might try inactivating these with `subpanel.SetAcceleratorTable(wx.NullAcceleratorTable)` for each subpanel.